# Firebase auth:1.0.0 Not Working for Facebook and Twitter

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I’m trying to implement firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0 in my Android App. I started by downloading and installing the FirebaseUI-Android demo from github (https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). I have successfully created Firebase users using all four methods (email, Google, Facebook, and Twitter) using this demo app.

Now I’m trying to implement firebase-ui-auth in my Android App. The email and Google methods work fine; the Facebook and Twitter methods fail. When “Sign in with Facebook” is clicked I briefly see the progress bar and then returned to the sign in page with no explanation as to why the sign in failed. When “Sign in with Twitter” is clicked, the Twitter page “Authorize myApp to use your account?” appears; upon clicking “Allow” I return to sign in page and a Toast is shown stating “Unable to complete the action”

I have setup my app in both Facebook and Twitter. Inserted both of their App IDs and App secrets into the my App’s Firebase console and inserted the Firebase Callback URL in both the Facebook and Twitter consoles. I’ve also inserted my Android Key Hash in the Facebook console.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts on how to get the Facebook and Twitter auth working is much appreciated.

My app’s build.gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lbconsulting.coachslog"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

// Google
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
// Firebase
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.8.0'

// Firebase UI
//    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'

// FirebaseUI Database only
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.0'

// FirebaseUI Auth only
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.0.0'

// FirebaseUI Storage only
//    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.0.0'

// Timber and Butterknife
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'

// Event Bus
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
// Gson
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'

// Facebook
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In my App’s onCreate() I initialize the Firebase Auth with the following code:

```
// Initialize Firebase Auth
     mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        startActivity(AuthUiActivity.createIntent(AthletesActivity.this));
        finish();
        return;
    } else {
```

My AuthUiActivity code is:

```
public class AuthUiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String FIREBASE_TOS_URL =
        "https://www.firebase.com/terms/terms-of-service.html";

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;

@BindView(android.R.id.content)
View mRootView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Timber.i("onCreate()");

    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(AthletesActivity.createIntent(this));
        finish();
    }
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setTheme(AuthUI.getDefaultTheme())
                    .setLogo(AuthUI.NO_LOGO)
                    .setProviders(getSelectedProviders())
                    .setTosUrl(getSelectedTosUrl())
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Timber.i("onActivityResult()");
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        handleSignInResponse(resultCode, data);
        return;
    }
    showSnackbar(R.string.unknown_response);
}

@MainThread
private void handleSignInResponse(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        startActivity(AthletesActivity.createIntent(this));
        finish();
        return;
    }

    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        showSnackbar(R.string.sign_in_cancelled);
        return;
    }

    if (resultCode == ResultCodes.RESULT_NO_NETWORK) {
        showSnackbar(R.string.no_internet_connection);
        return;
    }

    showSnackbar(R.string.unknown_sign_in_response);
}

@MainThread
private List<IdpConfig> getSelectedProviders() {
    List<IdpConfig> selectedProviders = new ArrayList<>();

    selectedProviders.add(new IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build());

    selectedProviders.add(
            new IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER)
                    .setPermissions(getFacebookPermissions())
                    .build());

    selectedProviders.add(
            new IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                    .setPermissions(getGooglePermissions())
                    .build());

    selectedProviders.add(new IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.TWITTER_PROVIDER).build());

    return selectedProviders;
}

@MainThread
private List<String> getFacebookPermissions() {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    // TODO: do we need to get Facebook user_friends and user_photos
//        result.add("user_friends");
//        result.add("user_photos");
    return result;
}

@MainThread
private List<String> getGooglePermissions() {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    // TODO: do we need to get Google Games and Drive_file?
//        result.add(Scopes.GAMES);
//        result.add(Scopes.DRIVE_FILE);
    return result;
}

@MainThread
private String getSelectedTosUrl() {
//        if (mUseGoogleTos.isChecked()) {
//            return GOOGLE_TOS_URL;
//        }
// TODO: create terms of service and save it in Firebase
    return FIREBASE_TOS_URL;
}

@MainThread
private void showSnackbar(@StringRes int errorMessageRes) {
    if (mRootView != null) {
        Snackbar.make(mRootView, errorMessageRes, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public static Intent createIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(context, AuthUiActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    return intent;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following repository to your gradle:

app/build.gradle

```
android {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
...
```

Comment: Thanks, Jeffrey for your suggestion. Unfortunately  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } was already in my repositories.

Comment: Place it in the app,'s build. gradle within the Android brackets.